# Apply custom css class while rendering an image

Tags: 7

Here I want to add an attribute for custom css class, is this possible using field_view_value, `field_menu_image` is my image's machine name

```
$image = field_get_items('node',node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'field_menu_image');                         
$output=field_view_value('node', node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'field_menu_image',$image[0]);
print render ($output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

field_view_value returns a renderable array so you should be able to just do.

```
$image = field_get_items('node',node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'field_menu_image');                         
$output=field_view_value('node', node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE), 'field_menu_image',$image[0]);
$output['#item']["attributes"]["class"] = array('test');
print render ($output);
```